# Boto cannot iterate through instances

Tags: python, boto

The following code returns an empty list:

```
instancelist = list()
instancelist = [x for x in conn.get_all_instances()]

for instance in instancelist:
       print instance.groups
```

In every case the code never enters the for loop, could you please provide insight on why this is?

The boto API is supposed to return a list of all the reservation objects from conn.get_all_instances. 
I am able to run/kill instances from the same connection object just fine.

Comment: Your list comprehension is unnecessary. Just try `instancelist = conn.get_all_instances()` (which probably didn't cause the error, but is really superfluous)

Comment: Maybe there... just aren't any instances? Why do you expect there to be instances? What is an instance?

Comment: Exactly. Check the contents of the list in a debugger, and check if your connection really gets established. Maybe you're closing it before reading?

Comment: the instances are there, I am able to create and destroy them, the connection is fine.  How can I see the contents of the list in a debugger

Answer (score 2):

Can you just try doing this:

```
>>> import boto
>>> boto.set_stream_logger('foo')
>>> conn = boto.connect_ec2(debug=2)
>>> conn.get_all_instances()
```

and see what gets printed to your console?  This should enable full debug logging of the request and response to the EC2 service so we will know exactly what is being asked for and what is being returned.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a definite Python newbie, but I currently use the following to iterate through all instances and return the list of groups:

```
import boto

conn = boto.connect_ec2()
all_instances = conn.get_all_instances()

for i in all_instances:
    print i
    for instance in i.instances:
        print instance.groups
```

I think the problem you may be having is that reservations are returned as a collection of instances.

As I said, I may be wrong, but the above works for me.